# Checking for rights

Tags: asp.net

I am building an application in asp.net using C# where people have their own profiles, and if they want to see others profile they can, but they only have read permission; how to set all these read write permissions in Ms Sql?

Comment: Are you handling the permissions at the application level or the database level?  In other words, are you handling disabling the ability to write within ASP.NET or sql server?

Comment: m sorry i do not know about 'acceptance'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way you can hide/show the controls based the user id on asp.net side. 
Then there is no need to actually do the work on DB level since user does not have any ability to do that via UI.

pseudo code:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender,Eventargs e)
if(!Page.IsPostBack){
 string userid= //get the id of the user whose profile you want to see
 string loggeduserid=//get the id of the logged in user
 bool visible = userid==loggeduserid
 ShowHideControls(visible)
}
}
private void(bool visible){
   btnEdit.Visible=visible;
   btnDelete.Visible = visible;
   //set other controls' visibility.
}
```

This is one way. You can refine the code above as per the need.
I will suggest you do it on your code level itself instead of DB because essentially you will be doing the same check if it were in a storedproc.